# tinymce implementation with php

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I newly tried to use TinyMCE in my website but the problem was that by very simple implementation of it in very basic page mentioned in the TinyMCE website I got unexpected result. With the following code the browser only display the large blank area with only a save button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"       
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>TinyMCE Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<!-- OF COURSE YOU NEED TO ADAPT NEXT LINE TO YOUR tiny_mce.js PATH -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas"
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- OF COURSE YOU NEED TO ADAPT ACTION TO WHAT PAGE YOU WANT TO LOAD WHEN HITTING   
"SAVE" -->
<form method="post" action="show.php">
    <p>     
            <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15">This is some content that will  
be editable with TinyMCE.</textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me what the problem is with the code and the page showed in browser. I can say that I got the same result with different browsers.

Comment: When you view the console in your browser, are there any error messages or warnings?

Comment: no  errors, no messages. I have already checked javascript enable in the browser setting and I am sure every things OK with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put all tiny `mce` `library` files
it will work when all files are there.

please download latest `tiny mce` here

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php