# tinyMCE is not working

Tags: php, html, tinymce, textarea

I am building a site with PHP and MYSQL. I have extracted tiny_mce to htdocs root folder of apache..now the directory is like `htdocs\jscripts\tiny_mce`..
Now i have included the tiny_mce.js and wrote the basic js script.and then created a form which consists of a `<textarea rows="12" cols="80" name="question" id="question">&nbsp;</textarea>`

But still the result is the same: my browser is showing normal textarea with a submit button. Nothing is working, and teaxt indentation(i.e. WYSIWYG) is not achieved.

I have googled a lot on this topic, and found a post on this site: [tinymce implementation with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772441/tinymce-implementation-with-php).

The conclusion of this post was I have to include al js files. So i did it. But there is a problem.inside of tiny_mce folder there are another four folders (lang,themes,plugins,utils) and three js scripts. So i have included all thsose three scripts, and from those folders plugins have 88 folders inside of it, and there are loads of js scripts, so it's impossible to include them all.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/langs/en.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/utils/editable_selects.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/utils/form_utils.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/utils/form_utils.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/utils/mctabs.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/utils/validate.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 tinyMCE.init({
 mode : "textareas"
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="post.html.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" maxlength="200" name="title" value="" id="title" />
    <textarea rows="12" cols="80" name="question" id="question">&nbsp;</textarea>
    <input type="image" src="post.png" alt="post your que" name="post" value="post" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="post" />
 </form>
 </body>
 <html>
```

It's still showing only a normal text area, and text indentation(i.e. WYSIWYG) is not achieved. What have I done wrong?

**EDIT 1:ERRORS**

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EditorManager' of null
  tiny_mce_popup.js:5 2
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseURI' of undefined
  form_utils.js:11
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'windowManager' of undefined
  mctabs.js:13
- Object {majorVersion: "3", minorVersion: "5.8", releaseDate:
  "2012-11-20", _init: function, is: function…}

  wall.html.php:47

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: no error no message...

Comment: Add `console.log(tinyMCE)` just before `tinyMCE.init`. What's the output?

Comment: saame again..no error no message

Comment: What's the console output? Don't tell me you are not using the debug console like Firebug, Chrome Developer tools or IE Developer Tools.

Comment: i have added `console.log(tinyMCE) just before tinyMCE.init`..and then run it with chrome browser..and then there was same output.. no erros.

Comment: that's what i have done..if there's anyother way to get the console output..please instruct me..i dont know how to do that

Comment: Press F12 in chrome. Google "Chrome Developer Tools". Read. Learn. Debug.

Comment: please have alook at the edits..i have updated the reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out is that your path *may* be wrong. Try using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Or type out the absolute URL. You only need to include that one file, not all the others. The other scripts are plugins generally, which you would include using the advanced theme. Secondly, I would specify the simple theme for now:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    theme : "simple"
});
```

Other than that, use Firebug to try and debug it.

Comment: i have updated my errors..can u please explain

Comment: Does it work now? Try putting this parameter in the init too: debug: true, not sure but I think it's a valid param.

Comment: I don't know what path your calling script is in, but by using / instead of ../ you're telling it to start at the webroot instead of just going up one directory from the current one.

Comment: YES..I HAVE MADE A SILLY MISTAKE...MAY BE THA'S WHY I HAVE BEEN VOTED DOWN..BUT IN OTHER WEBSITES IT(JSSCRIPT FOLDER) WAS WRITTEN THAT I HAVE TO KEEP IT IN ROOT DIRECTORY...AND THE SRC THEY USED LIKE WHAI I HAVE WRITTEN IN THE POST..SO IT WAS GIVING PATH ERROR..HAVE FIXED IT,THANKS AND SORRY FOR THE DISTURB